# Command line error stock magento

Tags: magento2, command-line, command

I get this error after install when trying to clear var/ generation, and static content deploy via command line.

```
[Exception] Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Config/Processor/Fallback.php on line 125
```

Comment: Try upgrade command... Bin/magento setup:upgrade then di:compile and static-content:deploy

Comment: I get an error that it can't create the directory. Permissions/ Ownership?

Comment: Well for now just set 777 permission to all directories. After that you can set permission as per security concerns.

Comment: Still same error message.

Comment: You are on local machine with Ubuntu?if yes take a look here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98699/51548

Comment: Have you found a solution?
The same problem to me https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191088/magento-broken-after-module-disable

Answer (score 6):

The problem was in app/etc/env.php file which was empty.

I restored the content of this file with the local data and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when trying to build a magento site when the DB is not reachable and the config file doesn't have any stores set.

You should be able to run `php bin/magento app:config:dump` on a working instance to see what `app/etc/config.php` and `app/etc/env.php` should look like. The minimum we have got it to is:
**app/etc/config.php**

```php
<?php
return array(
    'modules' =>
        array(
            ...
        ),
    'scopes' =>
        array(
            'websites' =>
                array(
                    'admin' =>
                        array(
                            'website_id' => '0',
                            'code' => 'admin',
                            'name' => 'Admin',
                            'sort_order' => '0',
                            'default_group_id' => '0',
                            'is_default' => '0',
                        ),
                    'uk' =>
                        array(
                            'website_id' => '2',
                            'code' => 'uk',
                            'name' => 'United Kingdom',
                            'sort_order' => '2',
                            'default_group_id' => '2',
                            'is_default' => '1',
                        ),
                ),
            'groups' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                        array(
                            'group_id' => '0',
                            'website_id' => '0',
                            'code' => 'default',
                            'name' => 'Default',
                            'root_category_id' => '0',
                            'default_store_id' => '0',
                        ),
                    2 =>
                        array(
                            'group_id' => '2',
                            'website_id' => '2',
                            'code' => 'united_kingdom_group',
                            'name' => 'United Kingdom',
                            'root_category_id' => '1838',
                            'default_store_id' => '2',
                        ),
                ),
            'stores' =>
                array(
                    'admin' =>
                        array(
                            'store_id' => '0',
                            'code' => 'admin',
                            'website_id' => '0',
                            'group_id' => '0',
                            'name' => 'Admin',
                            'sort_order' => '0',
                            'is_active' => '1',
                        ),
                    'uk' =>
                        array(
                            'store_id' => '2',
                            'code' => 'uk',
                            'website_id' => '2',
                            'group_id' => '2',
                            'name' => 'United Kingdom',
                            'sort_order' => '0',
                            'is_active' => '1',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
);
```

**app/etc/env.php**

```php
<?php
return array (
  'system' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'dev' => 
      array (
        'js' => 
        array (
          'minify_files' => '1',
          'merge_files' => '0',
          'enable_js_bundling' => '0',
        ),
        'css' => 
        array (
          'merge_css_files' => '0',
          'minify_files' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'cache_types' => 
  array (
    'compiled_config' => 1,
  ),
);
```

You will need to update `app/etc/config.php` to match your store information, list can be obtained from the db tables:
- `store`
- `store_group`
- `store_website`

Hope this helps