# Magento broken after module disable

Tags: magento2, upgrade, deploy

I have a huge problem with Magento on a live platform.
I've **disabled** a few modules, which I don't use, via a command line.

I've made it before already and had no problems with it. 
But now I can't upgrade or deploy.

**I get this error:**

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Config/Processor/Fallback.php on line 125
```

I've enabled the modules again, but the error stays.

What could I do?
Appreciate any help.

---

Solved
etc/env.php had only two lines. After reconstructing it from the backup everything is fine - except images in backend. Don't see product images and can't upload new.

Comment: as modules might change the database structure, it is not always trivial to disable modules once enabled.

Comment: I see... But I what could I do now?

Comment: best this is, save your orders and go back to your latest backup. If you want to fix it, make sure you have a clean cache, rebuild your index and redeploy to pub. If this doesn't help you need some developer to look into this

Answer (score 0):

Stop cron from running before the upgrade.  Then after upgrading, check app/etc/env.php

There's a good chance it became corrupt.  Problem found here [enter link description here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7165)

Hopefully you have a backup.  Open the backup and copy the contents from app/etc/env.php to your new app/etc/env.php and save

Run setup:upgrade again.